# HTTP Status Code 404 or 501 when Operation is not supported by a Resource in REST

Tags: rest, http

I have a REST Service and depending on the type of Resource that is being viewed I have certain Operations avialable

So `Resource1` supports `Operation1` and `Operation2`

eg:

```
Resource1/Operation1

Resource1/Operation2
```

And `Resource2` only supports `Operation1`

eg:

```
Resource2/Operation1
```

So if I receive a call for `Operation2` on `Resource2` (eg: `Resource2/Operation2`) the server will not raise an error as Operation2 is valid, but internally I don't support it, so should I return a 404 - Not Found or would a 501 - Not Implemented be more accurate or another error code?

Comment: because `Resource2` isn't capable of performing `Operation2`, a `404` is more relevant in my opinion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to think in terms of Resources (that exist and you operate on them) and not Services as in WebServices (which you call to do something).

So every *Operation* of your REST API is a resource by itself (i.e. to model long running operations or some sort of more complex transaction that are triggered by sending a *POST* request to the operation resource) - and the URI to that resource is any opaque string, which can be 'Resource1/Operation1' or "/someOther/arbitrary/path",

A 501 means the HTTP server itself has a particular feature not implemented that is require to fulfill the request - i.e. it lacks some technical features - but the resource itself is valid.

But as you've written, your Rest API is not designed to support Operation2 for Resource2 at all, which means that there is no such thing as a "Resource2/Operation2" service resource. Therefore 404 response is the only reasonable choice.

In terms of "how client will interact...", ask yourself: given *you* are the consumer of a resource (i.e. some arbitrary web site), will you revisit the same URL when receiving a 404? (probably not) will you do when receiving a 501? (probably yes, as you assume the problem has been resolved in the meantime)

**TL;DR**

return 404

Comment: Does HTTP 404 not imply that the request from the client is semantically correct, but the resource(s) requested are just not found?

Comment: exactly, where "not found" == "not exists" == "user has probably not enough permissions to see the resource" (especially the latter one is not uncommon but also not obvious). From the information given to the server to serve the resource, the server comes to the conclusion, the resource does not exist for the user

Comment: But the client's request is not semantically correct; it's not a permissions problem. As I understand it the request is illegal for any client. Period.

Comment: 405 is literally "operation not allowed".
But since the operation is exposed as a resource this really is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Never return any HTTP 5XX status from you code. It's used by the server to report server internal problem. If you are using that it would be confusing for the application user. So just use 404 for your purpose.

Comment: I think this is correct in the current context. I just want to make clear that 5xx status codes can be returned from code. Thinking of _502 Bad Gateway_ and _504 Gateway Timeout_, if a request has to be proxied and fails, or _503 Service Unavailable_ if there is a temporary problem with an internal resource

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of them,

its your webapis , depend upon how the client will interact with it.

> 4xx is for client error and 5xx is for server error

you may use 
**501** *Not Implemented* instead of **404** *not found*

because the resource in url is not there .

> OR you can also use

your own custom error code and error message.

or

**422** Unprocessable Entity
The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.

Comment: HTTP 404 and 422 both imply that he request is semantically correct. As I understand the OP, the request is in fact not correct.

Comment: so you can go with 501

Comment: From Wikipedia: "The server either does not recognize the request method, or it lacks the ability to fulfill the request. Usually this implies future availability (e.g., a new feature of a web-service API)". So HTTP 501 would still tell the client that it's request was valid - which seems to be misleading here.

Answer (score 0):

If the client request by definition is illegal, I would return **HTTP 400 Bad Request**.

Sending HTTP 400 also implies that the request should not merely be retried, as it is permanently illegal and is not understood by he server.

Only reservation I would have with using HTTP 400 is that it usually seems to be used for malformed requests; i.e. typos and the like. Whether your request is illegal or malformed, is a question of semantics.

Comment: 400 is more reasonable for bad syntax. For example, passing XML in the body instead of JSON, or if your request is missing certain required properties.