# Should an optional, statically-defined resource that is unimplemented be defined as 403 or 501 (or something else)?

Tags: api, http, openapi

I have a device for which I am implementing an HTTP API and defining it via OpenAPI 3.0.
The following paths are defined:

```
/scan/inventory/start
/scan/location/start
/scan/direction/start
```

This API is designed to run on various devices, but not all of them implement the `location` or `direction` feature, but all do implement the `inventory` feature. The available features can be queried by GETing the `/scan` path.

For a device that does not support `location` my team has been waffling on the error code to return if someone attempts to use it. We want to provide useful feedback when this happens, so 404 seems ruled out, especially since the path is documented in our API. After reading and re-reading RFC-7231 and various summaries of it, 501 or 403 seemed like good choices.

At first, "501 Not Implemented" seemed like a good choice, but the 5XX class of errors seems to suggest a more serious server error.

Since we want to provide feedback, "403 Forbidden" seems good and puts the onus on the client for accessing a bad path.

I'm sure part of the problem is that we're attempting to use a specification (HTTP) that was not necessarily designed for arbitrary APIs.

What would you suggest we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

[`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) isn't right, since that indicates that the user isn't "authorized" to access that resource. It implies that the issue lies on the client side. But in this case there simply is no resource.

[`501`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.2) isn't right, since that "indicates that the server does not support the functionality required to fulfill the request. This is the appropriate response when the server does not recognize the request method and is not capable of supporting it for any resource." In this case the server has no problem supporting the request, it's just that the resource doesn't exist.

Note that "server" refers to the *web server*. The issue isn't whether or not your application as a whole supports some bit of functionality, it's whether the web server is capable of handling the HTTP request it was sent. It's not appropriate to use HTTP status codes to indicate that kind of high-level application state.

Also note that the status code isn't just a private contract between your application and its users. All actors in the web stack—loggers, intermediate caches, browsers, etc.—might change their behavior depending on the status code. That's why it's important to reserve things like `5xx` for actual server errors.

To summarize, since the resource at that URI doesn't exist, the best way to provide useful feedback is to return a `404`. If you want to distinguish between features that are never supported and those that are simply unsupported for that device you should use a mechanism other than the status code. Fortunately you're off to a good start by listing the available features at `/scan`.

Comment: 401 is explicitly for Unauthorized.  
403 is Forbidden, and the "request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials". It seems possible that if an endpoint is defined  by the spec, but the hardware does not support it, it may be a forbidden operation.   

The only question I have about 501 not being valid is that the quote you provide is an example of usage, but it doesn't state the converse to be true -- though I made the same argument to my team.

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid anything. `404` seems reasonable, but it's also true that the "server does not support the functionality required to fulfill the request". As described in the question, the application runs on different kinds of devices, but not all of them can support every feature of the API. So... is it the client's error for requesting a feature that is not implemented (404), or the server's (501)?

Comment: @Bryant: "Server" refers to something quite specific: a *web server*. (See RFC 7230 for more.) The fact that your application doesn't support some functionality is very different from saying that the web server isn't capable of fulfilling a request. I think this gets to the heart of the issue: the HTTP protocol is not the appropriate place to express this kind of application state. Imagine if, instead of two states, you had more ("used to be supported but now deprecated", "will be supported in the next release", etc.). You wouldn't try to come up with a different status code for each, right?

Comment: @Bryant: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35312004/2395796) is an answer making the same argument, see if you find it more persuasive than mine.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I was thinking of the server as the entire application and not just the web server. Thanks for taking the time to go through this. Maybe add this bit about the the application being different from the web server to your answer?

Comment: @Bryant: Happy to help. I updated the answer based on our discussion.